# Laravel Route to other port/application

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel 8 project running on port 8000 and metabase (an analytic framework) running on port 3000.

metabase itself is password protected. But if possible I would like to make normal users unable to even get to the login screen of metabase. My idea was that metabase exposes port 3000 only to localhost and laravel forwards port 3000 inside a middlewarte protected route.

I was hoping for a solution which would look something like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth','isAdmin'])->prefix('metabase')->group(function() {
    // forward port 3000 here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Laravel can't protect endpoints outside of his requests. Instead, you can use HTTP auth or maybe you can try subdomain routing https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing